# Why am I able to run in android studio but assembleRelease fails with illegal start of type?

Tags: java, android

I have been building (both run and assembleRelease) just fine until I simply moved my project. After just moving the project files now assemble release fails with this message but I can still press the play button and run it on my device just fine.

```
/Users/james/AndroidStudioProjects/CompanyName/AppName/CompanyName/src/main/java/com/foo/ShipmentDetailRecyclerViewAdapter.java:29: illegal start of type
   private List<Commodity> mCommodities = new ArrayList<>();
                                                        ^
/Users/james/AndroidStudioProjects/CompanyName/AppName/CompanyName/src/main/java/com/foo/ShipmentStatusSelectionActivity.java:95: illegal start of type
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                                                     ^
2 errors
:AppName:compileMockReleaseJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':AppName:compileMockReleaseJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.22 secs
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
6:01:11 PM: External task execution finished 'assembleRelease'.
```

It looks like its failing to be able to do [Type Inference for Generic Type Instance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html). I am however using jdk 8 and I would assume since it was working just fine in the past I don't understand whats happening. I have been spinning my wheels on this for awhile now. Could it be that some how when I moved the project and re-imported it the java level was set back to 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue recently. Turned out my system Java home was set to 1.6 with no support for automatic type inference for generics. The build worked well in Android Studio because the project itself was configured correctly to use JDK 1.7.

Would be worth checking your environment variables and ensuring JAVA_HOME is set to at least 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was going on but eventually I discovered rebooting my macbook fixed the problem. I had tried restarting Android studio with no change... Never underestimate the power of rebooting your whole machine... sign...